# Easiest way for a tourist to buy spices in Hong Kong

Tags: food-and-drink, shopping, hong-kong

As a tourist to Hong Kong what's the easiest way to get local spices, particularly Sichuan Pepper.

By easiest I mean somewhere that may speak English or have English labels and would pack them in some way that they can be transported back by plane safely. Ideally pre-packed and labeled in English as that would avoid any potential customs issues.

Alternatively I can borrow a local or have the Chinese wording but I would have thought there'd be some foodie shop aimed at tourists that does stuff like this. Anything like pre-packed 'gift baskets' with an assortment of spices would be perfect.

Comment: What is easiest stand for? largest variety? English User-friendly? Delivery services?

Comment: @Him, I tried to make that clear but largely 'clueless English-speaking tourist friendly' is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest option is almost certainly the nearest supermarket, but if you're looking for something a little more tarted up and are willing to pay the corresponding premium, you could do worse than [Regency Spices](http://regencyspices.hk/).  They've got a 14-piece "[Chinese Spices Starter Kit](http://regencyspices.hk/ingredients/chinese-herbs-spices/chinese-spices-starter-kit)" (HKD 328, ~US$42) and will even ship it worldwide for an extra $9.

Response to an e-mail asking if I could purchase directly at their [address](http://regencyspices.hk/contact) or order and collect there:

> You can do both at the same address! It may be easiest to order online for pickup as we pack and grind fresh, depending on what you're looking for some of our products take a while to prepare.

Comment: Interesting, they seem to be delivery only. Shame they don't have a store somewhere, although I guess I could have it delivered to the hotel (did we have a question around here about deliveries to hotels?).

Comment: @SpaceDog They do have a shop/office: http://regencyspices.hk/contact You'd likely need to ring them in advance, but I'm sure you could arrange to pick up there.

Comment: Awesome! I e-mailed them to check the logistics, I'll post any answer I get here. I'm surprised there's not a more touristy food shop somewhere but maybe there's not really that much demand. I'm going to leave this question a few days just in case anyone else has any other options.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me editing their response into your answer, looks like they're the closest to what I was looking for but I'm still interested to see if there are other options.